# Overfitting after one epoch

Tags: keras, cross-validation, recurrent-neural-network

I am training a model using Keras.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=300, input_shape=(timestep,103), use_bias=True, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=536))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

while True:
        history = model.fit_generator( 
            generator = data_generator(x_[train_indices],
                    y_[train_indices], batch = batch, timestep=timestep),
                steps_per_epoch=(int)(train_indices.shape[0] / batch), 
                epochs=1, 
                verbose=1, 
                validation_steps=(int)(validation_indices.shape[0] / batch), 
                validation_data=data_generator(
                    x_[validation_indices],y_[validation_indices], batch=batch,timestep=timestep))
```

It is a multiouput classification accoriding to scikit-learn.org definition:
***Multioutput regression assigns each sample a set  of  target values.This can be thought of as predicting several properties for each data-point, such as wind direction and magnitude at a certain location***.

Thus, it is a recurrent neural network I tried out different timestep sizes. But the result/problem is mostly the same.

After **one epoch**, my train loss is around 0.0X and my validation loss is around 0.6X. And this values keep stable for the next 10 epochs.

Dataset is around 680000 rows. Training data is 9/10 and validation data is 1/10.

I ask for intuition behind that..

- Is my model already over fittet after just one epoch?
- Is 0.6xx even a good value for a validation loss?

High level question:
Therefore it is a multioutput classification task (not multi class), I see the only way by using sigmoid an binary_crossentropy. Do you suggest an other approach?

Comment: I'm not sure - but I think that maximal value of `binary_crossentropy` is equal to `0.7` in your case. So `valid` loss might be pretty high. I would try to increase the `dropout` rate and check if such phenomenon still occurs.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to increase the Dropout. Could you point out that 0.7 max value?

Comment: I increased Dropout and Recurrent_Dropout to 0.4. But after one epoch I get a similar result:
loss: 0.0347 - acc: 0.9885 - val_loss: 0.6998 - val_acc: 0.9193

Comment: Try `0.7`. And then `bin search` for the best one if it not overfit.

Comment: Used even a 0.9 each, same picture. loss: 0.1068 - acc: 0.9645 - val_loss: 0.4846 - val_acc: 0.9199. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 9):

I've experienced this issue and found that the learning rate and batch size have a huge impact on the learning process. In my case, I've done two things.

- Reduce the learning rate **(try 0.00005)**
- Reduce the batch size **(8, 16, 32)**

Moreover, you can try the basic steps for preventing overfitting.

- Reduce the complexity of your model
- Increase the training data and also balance each sample per class.
- Add more regularization (Dropout, BatchNorm)

Comment: Generally I see your point, but in which way has the batch size influence on this?